# Error with docker login: no such host

Tags: ubuntu, docker, boot2docker, docker-registry

After starting up a private docker registry from the `registry` docker image, doing a login to the registry

```
docker login http://docker.mydomain.com:5000
```

causes the following error after typing in name, password and email:

```
FATA[0007] Error response from daemon: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://docker.mydomain.com:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup docker.mydomain.com: no such host. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry docker.mydomain.com:5000` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.mydomain.com:5000/ca.crt
```

Trying an insecure login does not work too:

```
docker login --insecure-registry http://docker.mydomain.com:5000
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

---

**nmap localhost**

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000010s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
5000/tcp open  upnp
```

**Visiting `http://docker.mydomain.com:5000` on browser:**

```
true
```

**Visiting `http://docker.mydomain.com:5000/v1/_ping` on the browser:**

```
{}
```

Comment: Would using the https url work better?

Comment: Is port `5000` opened on your host?

Comment: @VonC using the https url gives the same error

Comment: @SzymonStepniak `nmap localhost` shows that port 5000 is open: `5000/tcp open  upnp`

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the `--insecure-registry` flag - this is for your daemon not your client. As stated in the error message:

> please add `--insecure-registry docker.mydomain.com:5000` to the daemon's arguments.

You will need to add this to your daemon and restart it if you want to use your insecure private registry. Otherwise, just put it behind a web server that uses https and proxy it.